# Bootstrap accordion group issue

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am into a very dicey situation. I have a following accordion group which I want to open based on logic in the logic. I should also be allowed to open two tabs at a time. When the page loads the first tab should be also open. I have the following code and tried to use the expression the below way but was unsuccessful till now:

```
 <accordion close-others="true"  >
   <accordion-group data-ng-repeat="accordion in appTabMap[tabKey.id]" is-open="($index == 0 && accordion.enableValidation === '') || (accordion.enableValidation === 'true')">
  </accordion-group>     
</accordion>
```

Even if the `accordion.enableValidation` is true I am not able to open them I don't know why. If the tab is close the logic doesn't work to open the tab again. I am confused.

Comment: maybe add a jsfiddle ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are two issues:

1. `close-others` needs to equal `false`, if you want to open multiple groups.
2. The expression in `is-open` must be assignable, because Angular will update the value based on whether the group is open (`true`) or not (`false`). For example, `is-open="isOpen[$index]"`.

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/masa671/c3d5qgdb/

In addition, you should improve the way of handling boolean variables in JavaScript (`enableValidation`), but I did not fix that yet in the fiddle (to keep it closer to the original code).

**UPDATE:**

Another fiddle to demonstrate, how the `is-open` expressions can be re-evaluated (with the `Re-init` button): https://jsfiddle.net/masa671/jewap5om/

Comment: I tried this before .... This doesnt work when the tab is already open and then i close it by click .. Then it doesnt allow the isopen expression to open the tab..

Comment: You just need to tell Angular, when the `is-open` expressions should be re-evaluated. See my UPDATE above for how this can be done (with a button).

Comment: I used the similiar approach but it doesnt open here is my code    HTML code    <accordion-group   data-ng-repeat="accordion in appTabMap[tabKey.id]"   ng-click="reinit($index,accordion.enableValidation);" ng-init="tabInit($index,accordion.enableValidation);" is-open="{{isOpen}}" > JS code is in below comment

Comment: and the js code is below $scope.initTab = function(index,enableValidation) {        
         return (!index && enableValidation === '') || (enableValidation === 'true'); }; $scope.tabInit = function(index,enableValidation) {
 $scope.isOpen = $scope.initTab(index,enableValidation);  };  $scope.reinit = function (index,enableValidation) {$scope.tabInit(index,enableValidation); };

Comment: Please place the code to a fiddle. Then it is easier to discuss, how it should be modified.